# Prepared statements weird bug

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

My code:

```
public function select($tbl,$info,$cond = null) {
        if (!is_array($info)) {
            return false;
        }
        $query = "SELECT `" . implode("`,`", $info) . "` FROM " . $this->escapeString($tbl) . (is_null($cond) ? "" : " WHERE " . $this->generateConditions($cond));
        $query = $this->escapeString($query);
        if ($prep = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,$query)) {
            $types = "";
            if (!is_null($cond)) {
                $types = $this->generateTypes($cond,$types);
            }
            $params = array();
            array_push($params, $prep);
            array_push($params, $types);
            if (!is_null($cond)) {
                foreach ($cond as $key => $value) {
                    array_push($params, $value);
                }
            }
            if (call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", $this->refValues($params))) {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($prep);
                $results = array();
                $results[] = $prep;
                $row = new stdClass();
                foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
                    $results[] = &$row->$value;
                }
                if (call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_result", $results)) {
                    $resultArray = array();
                    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($prep)) {
                        error_log("[PROJECT] ROW: " . print_r($row,true));
                        array_push($resultArray, $row);
                    }
                    error_log("[PROJECT] TEST: " . print_r($resultArray,true));
                    mysqli_stmt_close($prep);
                    unset($prep);
                    return (count($resultArray) == 1) ? $resultArray[0] : (array)$resultArray;
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($prep);
                unset($prep);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is my php method to select something from the database. However there seems to be a bug:

```
$resultArray = array();
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($prep)) {
   error_log("[PROJECT] ROW: " . print_r($row,true));
   array_push($resultArray, $row);
}
error_log("[PROJECT] Array: " . print_r($resultArray,true));
```

You'd think that whatever these `$row` are are found in the array right?
Well here is the output (since the log is too long, I made a concept):

```
ROW: stdClass Object\n(\n    [token] => RUMtN0tWNDU3MDY3QjE0NDM4M1M=\n...
ROW: stdClass Object\n(\n    [token] => RUMtNU1DNjcwNjYxNTQyNjIxNTc=\n...
Array: stdClass Object\n(\n    [token] => RUMtN0tWNDU3MDY3QjE0NDM4M1M=\n,
stdClass Object\n(\n    [token] => RUMtN0tWNDU3MDY3QjE0NDM4M1M=\n
```

So while the rows are different, only one row appears in the array and that duplicated. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Not a weird bug at all `$results[] = __&__$row->$value;` Assign "by reference" is something you should only do if you understand how it works

Comment: I have 1 object, $row and its properties are set during the fetch request, then I add it to the array and its properties change. the problem is, that the properties are changing in the array as well. I would need to copy or clone the object so its properties become untouchable.